# Organ Donation Obligation

Tags: ethics

Mike has a genetic kidney disease, which caused his kidney to fail at the age of 7. Mike has a biological child named John, who Mike knew would have a 100% chance of getting the disease. Now John is 7 and is beginning to show signs of kidney failure. If he doesn’t receive a kidney soon, he will die. Is Mike obligated to donate his kidney to his son?

Comment: Is this HW? We can help if you describe the context of the course it was assigned for, and describe your attempt to answer it.

Comment: Not for a course. I know nothing of ethics really, and this just came up in a debate I overheard.

Comment: What else was the debate about, what were the positions of the debaters? Without ethical context and surrounding circumstances this is unanswerable. In a vacuum Mike is neither obligated nor not obligated to do anything. There is also something odd with the set up: if Mike's kidney already failed what use is it to John? One can say that Mike has a parental duty to his son, or that it would be virtuous to save him (but that does not necessarily create an obligation), or even that much depends on Mike's vs John's prognoses, e.g. sacrificing a life to save another life is never obligatory.

Comment: Mike is able to give a kidney and survive. Let's say, for the sake of the thought experiment, that Mike got both his kidneys replaced when he was younger.

Comment: To boil the question down, If person A forced person B into a situation where B needed something from A, is A obligated to give that to B

Comment: First, when you start contriving scenarios like this they lose ethical interest, ethics is for navigating real life. In this case, alternatives, such as dialysis, exist, as well as the transplant list. To create even a room for obligation one would have to rule out such alternatives. And no, you can not credibly rule them out by stipulation, ethics is not about resolving "unique" scenarios. Second, giving birth as "forcing" is questionable. And third, even contrived all the way this is unanswerable because it depends on the ethics one adopts. Which answer do you want: yes or no?

Comment: Sorry, to rephrase: If I cause someone to need something, am I obligated to give the person what I caused them to need.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that if Mike's kidneys are already failing, they would be of no use to anyone else?

Comment: But Mike is able to donate his kidneys. They were failing when he was younger, but then he got them replaced. He got both replaced.

Comment: My guess is that you want to say yes. I think on most ethical positions a vaguer obligation of care to the son would exist, but to narrow it down to obligation to donate, given its life threatening consequences, is far more controversial. It is more in the area of self-sacrifice, and while most would endorse self-sacrifice as virtuous and commendable in this situation, few would elevate it to a moral *obligation*. It is not an obligation to be a hero. Utilitarians would also have to weigh risks and benefits of one life over the other, and where that ends up is highly sensitive to details.